# jhipster - can't run local dev profile after deploying app to Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, intellij-idea, spring-boot, jhipster

After using the jhipster generator, I am able to successfully run the app on my local webserver with a local PostgresQL. I managed to deploy it to Heroku as well, but now when I try to run it locally in IntelliJ (as I have before deployment), (selecting 'dev profile', clicking on spring-boot:run) or running the Application main method,
I receive the following error (Heroku Database url is not configured):

```
    ... 123 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Heroku database URL is not configured, you must set --spring.datasource.heroku-url=$DATABASE_URL
    at com.mycompany.myapp.config.HerokuDatabaseConfiguration.dataSource(HerokuDatabaseConfiguration.java:62) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.mycompany.myapp.config.HerokuDatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dbf295a9.CGLIB$dataSource$0(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.mycompany.myapp.config.HerokuDatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dbf295a9$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fa41e789.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.mycompany.myapp.config.HerokuDatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dbf295a9.dataSource(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 124 common frames omitted
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.Application.main(Application.java:72)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:98)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:378)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
    ... 5 more
```

Plz excuse my n00bness.. is this by design or am I missing some steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of [this error](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/1501) and it has been fixed in the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

From the first line in your logs, the Heroku database URL is not configured

`Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Heroku database URL is not configured, you must set --spring.datasource.heroku-url=$DATABASE_URL`

Hopefully the following example will help:

https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/heroku/templates/src/main/java/package/config/_HerokuDatabaseConfiguration.java

Comment: Right, it makes sense that running HerokuDatabaseConfiguration in development mode would fail, because the DATABASE_URL is configured by Heroku  ( https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java#using-the-database_url-in-spring-with-java-configuration )  so it should only work in production. I just did a test, to get the app to run in development mode without causing the above error, I simply have to delete the HerokuDatabaseConfiguration file, and then the OnConditional inside of DatabaseConfiguration will cause the normal dev profile to run.